# How to use Custom Events in Vue JS 2.+

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

What is the proper way to use the custom event in vue js 2.+

```
<submitButton v-on:formsubmit="onFormSubmit"/>
```

In Submit Button Component I trigger the event like this

```
this.$emit('formsubmit');
```

Comment: That's correct so far. Have you defined the `onFormSubmit` method in your component?

Comment: Yes inside methods

Answer (score 0):

Seems ok for me, maybe the issue comes from somewhere else. You can check the fiddle where I modified to test the custom event:
https://jsfiddle.net/Mark_f/u06dmhfn/125/

```
Vue.component('surprise-app', {
  template: `<button @click="surprise">Surprise Me!</button>`,
  data() {
    return {
      surprise: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    surprise() {
      this.$emit('formsubmit')
    },
  },
})
new Vue({
  el: '#surpriseApp',
  data: {
    surpriseMessage: null,
  },
  methods: {
    surpriseMe() {
      this.surpriseMessage = 'you got surpried';
    },
  },
});
```

However, according to [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names), it's better to use kebab-case for event names.